# Android переход в сообщения

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно по нажатию кнопки перейти в Сообщения андроида и уже чтобы был вписан номер к кому нужно отправить и готовый текст. Текст и номер статичны они не меняються

Comment: Что за `Сообщения андроида`? Это какое-то приложение? Если да, то надо Intent отправить на его запуск, положив туда данные. Какой именно Intent и какие данные - надо выяснять у автором приложения. Возможно, это у них просто не реализовано - тогда это попросту невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не я имею ввиду sms-ку надо отправить

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112012/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб там не показано как указать номер и текс смс. Как это реализовать

Comment: Там указано. Смотрите ответ от `answered May 9 '16 at 9:22`